# Add axis labels in svm plot in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, svm, matlab-figure

I am using svm for anomaly detection. I am using 2-dimensional data.

```
svmStruct = svmtrain(trf3,labeln1,'kernel_function','rbf','ShowPlot',true,'method','QP');
ok1 = svmclassify(svmStruct,testf3,'ShowPlot',true);
```

so in above training and testing figure shows but I want figure with xlabel and ylabel names. How can I add these to the `axes`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `svmclassify` simply plots data to a standard `axes` object, you can use `xlabel` and `ylabel` to add your own custom labels to the plot. Alternately, if you wan to be a little more explicit, you can retrieve the `axes` handle using [`gca`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/gca.html) and pass that as the first input to [`xlabel`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xlabel.html) and [`ylabel`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ylabel.html).

```
ok1 = svmclassify(svmStruct,testf3,'ShowPlot',true); 
xlabel('My X Label')
ylabel('My Y Label')
```